# Como buscar dados do PhpMyAdmin para exibir na tela utilizando Drupal 8?

Tags: php, aplicação-web, drupal

Criei uma tabela no [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) com algumas siglas que utilizo no trabalho, e preciso jogar esses dados no conteúdo de uma página que criei. Como eu faria isso? 
 *Estou trabalhando com o DRUPAL 8*.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, a resposta do [@ndvo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/30729/ndvo) trouxe solução pra você?

Answer (score 0):

Se você criou a tabela no mesmo banco que o Drupal utiliza, você pode usar o db_query para buscar o conteúdo.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de uma *Static Query* (busca estática). Como você mesmo criou a tabela no PHPMyAdmin, estou supondo que se trata de uma consulta relativamente simples.

```
$query = db_query("SELECT * FROM {NomeDaSuaTabela}");
$records = $query->fetchAll();
```

As *Static Queries* (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/static-queries e https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_query/8.4.x) só deveriam ser usadas para buscas simples, preferencialmente que não utilizem tabelas que possam ser modificadas via interface do Drupal.

Para buscas mais complexas utilize *Dynamic Queries* (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_query/8.4.x).

Considerando que se tratam de siglas, eu sugeriria usar a Taxonomia ao invés de uma tabela própria.